# For WCF Web service how to allow nullable fileds in data contract

Tags: web-services, wcf, nullable, datacontract, datafield

I have a WCF web service with data contract as

```
[DataContract]
public class Employee
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]        
    public int EmployeeNumber {get;set;}

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]        
    public string EmployeeName {get;set;}     

    [DataMember (IsRequired = true)]        
    public int DepartmentNumber{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to make DepartmentNumber field nullable. Because not always I will provide DepartmentNumber.

I tried the below mentioned code to achieve this

```
   [DataMember (IsRequired = true)]        
    public int? DepartmentNumber{ get; set; }
```

When I tried to test this using WCF client, it is not allowing me to enter anything for DepartmentNumber field.

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Have you tried to remove (IsRequired = true) if you want a nullable field?

Comment: Yes, In spite of removing (IsRequired  = true) it is not working

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by "it is not allowing me to enter anything for DepartmentNumber field". If you try to execute your service with an empty value for DepartmentNumber any error happens?